# I am getting the 404 Not Found error even through the route is present

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I am getting the following error

**404 NOT FOUND**

even if the route exists.

**Controller:**

```
public function index($id = NULL)
{
if($id){
$tasks = Task::where('project_id', $id)->get();
} else {
$tasks = Task::all();
}

$project = Project::findOrFail($id)->load(['tasks']);
return view('task.index', compact('tasks','project'));
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/task/index/{id?}', [TaskController::class, 'index'])->name('task.index');
```

When I am directed to this page I cannot see it due to the error written above.

Can anyone kindly tell me where the problem is?

---

*Relationship defined in the Client model:*

```
public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Task::class, Project::class);
    }
```

*Relationship defined in the Project model:*

```
public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }
```

*Relationship defined in the Task model:*

```
public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
```

*TaskController:*

```
public function index($id = NULL)
    {
        $tasks = Task::all();
        $project = Project::find($id)->load(['tasks']);     
        return view('task.index', compact('tasks','project'));
    }
```

---

**clients**
*id* - integer
*name* - string

**projects**
*id* - integer
*client_id* - integer
*name* - string

**tasks**
*id* - integer
*project_id* - integer
*title* - string

Comment: in the resources/views/task folder, does the file index.blade.php exists ?

Comment: If the project does not exists it will throw an 404 also

Comment: how did you call it? with what url?

Comment: @mrhn <a class="nav-link" href="{{route('task.index')}}">All tasks</a>

Comment: @VincentG yes there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route should be accessible via `site.domain/task/index` and not `site.domain/task` if you want to be able to access with /task your route should be `Route::get('/task/{id?}', [TaskController::class, 'index'])->name('task.index');`
Pay attention on the url you specified in your routes.

Update :
in your controller

```
if($id){
  $tasks = Task::where('project_id', $id)->get();
  $tasks->load('project')
} else {
  $tasks = Task::with('project')->get();
}
return view('task.index', compact('tasks'));
```

then in your view may be something like this

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
  display $task->project->name
@endforeach
```

(if i am not wrong analyzed i assumed 1 project has many task and 1 task belongs to 1 project)

Comment: I call it like this: ```<a class="nav-link" href="{{route('task.index')}}">All tasks</a>```

Comment: please check again may be you are editing the wrong route file, make soure when you call php artisan route:list the task.index is shown

Comment: I realized that if I delete this line ```$project = Project::findOrFail($id)->load(['tasks']) ``` it's fine, so the problem is this line. I do not understand why

Comment: are you trying to display task with project or what, may be i can help to optimize your code

Comment: I am trying to display the name of the project which refers to that specific task

Comment: you shoul define the inverse of its relation, so in your controller you dont need to query project anymore. i will update my answer

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: always prints that project name for each specific task, but in my application there are tasks belonging to different projects, so for each task it should print the name of the corresponding project

Comment: Answering that will be out of the main queation's scope, we solved why are your route returned 404, for this you can mark my answer as accepted and post new question about relationship